# Glm with Poisson in R with no p-value?

Tags: r, nonparametric, poisson-distribution, p-value

I've been doing glm and thought I had it cracked but looking at some sites for interpreting results I realised R had displayed my results oddly.

```
> glm(Number.of.Fish~Julian.Date*Size.Class,na.action=na.omit,poisson)
Call:  glm(formula = Number.of.Fish ~ Julian.Date * Size.Class, family = poisson, 
    na.action = na.omit)
Coefficients:
                  (Intercept)                    Julian.Date  
                   -0.0315824                      0.0003701  
             Size.Classmedium              Size.Classmedium   
                    0.1247642                     -0.0268892  
              Size.Classsmall   Julian.Date:Size.Classmedium  
                    3.6317021                     -0.0005089  
Julian.Date:Size.Classmedium     Julian.Date:Size.Classsmall  
                           NA                     -0.0156465  
Degrees of Freedom: 355 Total (i.e. Null);  349 Residual
  (298 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      2196 
Residual Deviance: 1368         AIC: 2213
```

I've tried changing the code to family="poisson" but no change and I' afraid after that I'm stumped.

Comment: try  summary( glm(Number.of.Fish~Julian.Date*Size.Class,na.action=na.omit,poisson))

Comment: Just a little queory onto this. For some reason my medium size class turns up twice. I did change a mis-spelling of medium from mediun before but I don't understand why it is ding this now and ingnoring the large catagory

Comment: Can you show the summary output?  Have you attached the data frame? It's better not to, and to use the data= argument.

Comment: Size.Classmedium               0.1247642  0.6043109   0.206    0.836    
Size.Classmedium              -0.0268892  1.0112341  -0.027    0.979    
Size.Classsmall                3.6317021  0.4924481   7.375 1.65e-13 ***
Julian.Date:Size.Classmedium  -0.0005089  0.0029337  -0.173    0.862    
Julian.Date:Size.Classmedium          NA         NA      NA       NA    
Julian.Date:Size.Classsmall   -0.0156465  0.0024656  -6.346 2.21e-10 ***        This is what I get

Comment: You seem to have a trailing space, i.e., "medium " in some of your observations.